# session identification from web server log using java program

Tags: java, web

I have this kind of web log as a text file from that i want to find session from log by considering session time as 30 minutes.

```
1 in24.inetnebr.com 01/08/1995:00:00:01 GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt  200 1839 
2 in24.inetnebr.com 01/08/1995:00:00:34 GET  /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-06.txt  200 2303 
3 in24.inetnebr.com 01/08/1995:00:05:01 GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt  200 1839 
4 in24.inetnebr.com 01/08/1995:00:30:00 GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt  200 1839 
5 in24.inetnebr.com 01/08/1995:00:30:55 GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt  200 1839 
6 in24.inetnebr.com 01/08/1995:00:35:00 GET /shuttle/missions/sts-68/news/sts-68-mcc-05.txt  200 1839 
7 slppp6.intermind.net 01/08/1995:00:00:10 GET 
/history/skylab/skylab.html  200 1687 
8 slppp6.intermind.net 01/08/1995:00:00:32 GET /history/skylab/skylab-1.html  200 1659 


9 slppp6.intermind.net 01/08/1995:00:30:00 GET /history/skylab/skylab.html  200 1687 

10 slppp6.intermind.net 01/08/1995:00:35:10 GET 
/history/skylab/skylab.html  200 1687 
11 133.43.96.45 01/08/1995:00:00:16 GET /shuttle/missions/sts-69/mission-sts-69.html  200 10566 

12 133.43.96.45 01/08/1995:00:00:55 GET /shuttle/missions/sts-69/mission-sts-69.html  200 10566 

13 133.43.96.45 01/08/1995:00:30:16 GET /shuttle/missions/sts-69/mission-sts-69.html  200 10566 

14 133.43.96.45 01/08/1995:00:55:16 GET /shuttle/missions/sts-69/mission-sts-69.html  200 10566
```

Help me out to develop java program for finding session and what data structure i have to use.

```
 package com.pradip.test;

 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.text.ParseException; 
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.Date;
 import java.util.Scanner;

 public class SessionIdentification {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
    Scanner s=new Scanner(new File("E:\\me_3rd\\uniqueurl.txt"));
    BufferedWriter writer=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("E:\\me_3rd\\sessions.txt")));
    SimpleDateFormat format=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy:HH:mm:ss");

    Date d1;
    Date d2;
    while (s.hasNextLine()) {
        String line=s.nextLine();
        Scanner s1=new Scanner(new File("E:\\me_3rd\\ordertoIP.txt"));

        while(s1.hasNextLine()){
            Scanner s2=new Scanner(new File("E:\\me_3rd\\ordertoIP.txt"));
            String line1=s1.nextLine();

            String sline1[]=line1.split("");
             long id=Long.parseLong(sline1[0]);

            String timestamp=sline1[2];
            if(line.equals(sline1[1])){
                while (s2.hasNextLine()) {
                    String line2=s2.nextLine();

                    String sline2[]=line2.split(" ");
                     long id1=Long.parseLong(sline2[0]);

                    String timestamp1=sline2[2];

                    d1=format.parse(timestamp);
                    d2=format.parse(timestamp1);

                    long diff=d2.getTime()-d1.getTime();

                    long diffSeconds = diff / 1000 % 60;
                    long diffMinutes = diff / (60 * 1000) % 60;
                    long diffHours = diff / (60 * 60 * 1000) % 24;
                    long diffDays = diff / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

                    long seconds=(diffDays*24*60*60)+(diffHours*60*60)+(diffMinutes*60)+diffSeconds;

                    if(seconds<=1800){

                        continue ;

                    }
                    else{
                        String sessionboundry=id+" "+id1; //id1-1
                        break;
                    }
                }


            }
        }
    }
}

 }
```

This is I was try but i dont know what to try next

Comment: What do you mean by `develop java program for finding session`, writing in a log file?

Comment: this is web log analysis task and i want to write a java program for finding session of time periods 30 minutes

Comment: How you are writing logs into file. Post some code

Comment: Sir please look out at above code.I just want to know about logic...

Comment: First you have to put a key of sessionId from web under web server

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are developing in `JSF` or `JSP`. So, You can retrieve session id from the `FacesContext`. you just need to append this sessionId in your log, than you can filter the result. As you required

```
FacesContext fCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fCtx.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
String sessionId = session.getId();
```

As you are interested in reading and unique logs only under 30 min session. you can read file line by line and populate your list of logs according.
A rough sketch

1. Format your log file properly. web / Timestamp / method / state / action / status / session id etc.
2. Read log file line by line in String.
3. Split and save logs into ArrayList if match criteria (under 30 min).

Comment: Sir i want to write simple java program for finding different sessions from weblog but i dont understand how to do.

Comment: You can not differentiate between session until you put a key into logs. Like `sessionId` most appropriate for this